# Did the incident mentioned in "Kiba's Long Day" really occur in the anime?

Tags: naruto

In the anime episode Kiba's Long Day (Season 4, Episode 184) there's a premise that a outsider had infiltrated the Village Hidden in the Leaves and used an infectious agent before committing suicide.  Naruto has heard about Kiba "and the others" having dealt with this previous incident (and seems petulant about missing out).  From the subtitles of the open:

> **Naruto:** What do you mean by monitoring Akimaru?
>
> **Tsunade:** You know about the incident where someone from outside
>   infiltrated the village, right?
>
> **Naruto:** Yeah, I know about that. But I heard Kiba and the others
>   resolved that incident without any trouble.
>
> **Tsunade:** That's right.
>
> **Naruto:** Damn! That Kiba! I want a mission where I totally kick an
>   enemy's butt.
>
> **Tsunade:** To be exact, that's wrong.
>
> **Naruto:** What?
>
> **Tsunade:** Before Kiba and the others had the intruder in custody, he
>   swallowed a pellet and killed himself.

Is this previous incident that Tsunade and Naruto refer to something that is portrayed earlier in the anime series?  We'd seen some episodes where outsiders disguised themselves and entered the Village (and infiltration is a theme of later episodes as well). But "taking a pellet" to suicide doesn't match with anything I remember in the series to that point.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask here... can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Krazer: I'm asking if the reference to an outsider infilterating the village made by Lady Tsunade to Naruto (which incident he seems to have heard about) corresponds to something that happened "in story" in the earlier anime episodes.  I can think of a couple of earlier episodes, even one that involved Kiba, that featured such infiltration, but it doesn't seem to entirely match.

Comment: Episodes 136-220 of Naruto are all fillers.

Comment: It's not impossible for fillers to have their own continuity parallel to the main canon, but the very long filler series that was the last 80 or so episodes of Naruto pre-Shippuden/timeskip were rather abysmal(ly bad).  I wouldn't spend too much time / effort trying to make any sense out of them.  Enjoy them for their comedic value if you can, enjoy the extra screen-time for the neglected secondary characters, and then move on quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not related to any previous episode and is basically a filler episode. The intruder who died by "taking a pellet" is no-one that has been shown before.

It doesn't match completely because it isn't supposed to. It isn't following any story line provided by the manga. That is why its called a "filler".